# Fix bluetooth windows 10 drivers in MBP

Tags: bootcamp, windows, bluetooth, driver

In my macbook pro's bootcamp bluetooth does not work and in an attemp to fix it following the steps:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250233849 which are based on windows using its own bluetooth drivers instead of the ones apple provides.

I did not made it work (code 10) and deleted the broadcom 802.11ac Network adapter drivers which now I can't install again.

Can somebody show me where to find/ download the apple certificate or whatever broadcom 802.11ac Network adapter drivers and try to fix bluetooth problems?

[image: Broadcom 802.11 general]
[image: Broadcom 802.11 driver]
[image: Bluetooth apple driver]
[image: Bluetoothapplegeneral]

Comment: Which year/model mbp do you have?

Comment: MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)

Comment: Did you run Apple Software Update?

Comment: Nor the apple software update nor the automatic update worked :(

Comment: by following this post I downloaded the drivers from bootcamp and made the wifi  work [https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7892024?answerId=31512627022#31512627022]

Comment: to fix the blurtooth I decided to disable the original antena and buy a 8€ amazon one, it seems to work well

Comment: @MelchorLazaro When you pair your Bluetooth devices in Windows to the cheap Bluetooth antenna, do those devices still work with the integrated Broadom Bluetooth adapter when you reboot in to Mac OS, or do you need to re-pair each device? Or, do you not know since you use the cheap Bluetooth antenna for both Windows and Mac OS?

Comment: I had to repaired them but not 100% sure, each time I use windows I have to repair the keyboard but not the mouse. not sure why